# How to Create a Save as button for an image

Tags: javascript, html, save-as

I'm developing a Screenshot extension for Chrome, and would like to know how could I implement a 'Save as' button in Html/Javascript. Currently users only Right Click To 'Save as'. I'm new to Javascript & didn't exactly find a way how to do it online. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 download attribute, is it what you are looking for ?

```html
<img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" alt="Stack Overflow">
<br />
<a href="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" download>Save !</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a download link with `<a href="" download="yourFileName">Save as …</a>`. The [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download) will cause the resource to be downloaded instead of viewed in the browser.

Then, if you want the link to actually refer to the resource, use something like `yourAnchorNode.href = yourImageNode.src;`, or if you use a `<canvas>` element to display the picture (you didn’t specify it in your original question, unfortunately) use [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) or [`toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob):

```js
yourAnchorNode.href = yourCanvasNode.toDataURL();
```

or

```js
yourCanvasNode.toBlob((blob) => yourAnchorNode.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

Note that `toBlob` is an asynchronous operation.